# Datatables ajax source but local-only (DOM style) filter

Tags: jquery, datatables

This is regarding using JQuery Datatables plugin:

I'd like to use my server-side source but in terms of filter, I'd prefer to keep it the 'DOM way' if you know what I mean.. i.e. without firing a new XHR request to the server but simply work on what is already populated.

Any recommended/generally accepted best practice for this??

Comment: Please could you elaborate a little bit? From the above I'm guessing you want to populate the dataTable the first time from a server-side source? Also what is your server-side source?

Comment: Hi @vietech, My server-side source is a typical php script that spits out whatever that is needed by DataTables to populate its rows. Yes, my problem is that I want only one query to the server, probably using `bDeferRender`, main concern is any change in the `search` box should **not** fire any more query but only filter whatever is readily available in the table.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the correct way of doing what you're trying to achieve, but when I've been using dataTables I started using CSV files to populate a table to the DOM the once when the page loads first and then when that completes initialise the dataTable. So there is only one request. I'm now doing the same thing but using Google Spreadsheet's instead of CSV files, which is working great!

I will point out that my tables are very basic and not very big.

But I would go about this by using AJAX to first retrieve the data from your php page, create a HTML table and then initialise the dataTable.

Something like.....

```
$.ajax({
   type:'GET',
   url:'../yourdatasource.php',
   success: function(data){
      // Your code to create the HTML table
      $('#yourTable').dataTable();
   }
});
```

As I said there are probably better methods for doing this but I like to keep things simples.

Comment: That's exactly what I started doing! Started of fine until I want to add some page-turn callbacks and other functionalities and thinking I might be re-inventing the wheel if DataTables already support what I want to do natively... Just wanted to know if there's some better approach lol. Thanks @vietech.

Answer (score 0):

i thought about this because i needed this. But after a few hours i find solution. Datatables concept have two sides. Left side is a DOM processing and right side is a server-side. Difference between those two are...

DOM processing:
- load source data
- work with source data

Server-side processing
- load source data
- all interactions are sended as XHR request.
 (source: [Enhancing-HTML-tables-using-a-JQuery-DataTables-pl](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194916/Enhancing-HTML-tables-using-a-JQuery-DataTables-pl) "In this mode, the plug-in only handles interaction with the user, and all processing is done on the server side.")

So you can not join together these two sides because DOM work with data which has been loaded and server-side operate with data (database) live. If you want to enable this function in server-side processing, i think this is bad idea because in DOM is a "filtering" and in server-side is a "search". If the biggest difference between them. You can not ensure correct result if user will want to "filter" data.
If you have a lot of records, you should use server-side.
Otherwise load data and use DOM work.

and try this..
http://datatables.net/ref#bServerSide

I hope this help you as me
Have a nice day

**EDIT**

**If you want to load data from remote server and filter data which has been loaded via DOM filter, you can use "sAjaxSource": "xhr.php" for load data but you dont specify/enable bServerSide. It works fine.**

http://datatables.net/ref#sAjaxSource

Comment: Yes after a while I figured it is probably not part of datatables' design to do what I wanted to do. In fact, I ended up resorting to @vletech answer lol

Comment: Right. This is what i want to tell you. Use this combinations is bad idea. However you checked my link? May be much clear than @vletech answer.